# How to convert elements of NSMutableArray (NString) to NSNumber and add them up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsnumber

Ok so I have NsMutable array with Strings which are in format:

```
  32,45,54,5550 etc.
```

What is the easiest way to convert all these strings to nsnumber and also get the sum of entire array.

Comment: Loop over the array, convert each string to a numeric value (probably an int) and add them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the KVC collection operator [`@sum`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178593) to get the summation of all number strings stored in an array

```
NSArray *numberStrings = @[@"32",@"45",@"54",@"5550"];
NSNumber* sum = [numberStrings valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
NSLog(@"%@", sum);
```

output: `5681`

For simple strings it works. But caution: in localization there might be traps. There-for I would still suggest to use a [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create real NSNumber objects, store them in another array and use `@sum` on that.

---

<sub>Thanks  Bryan Chen for make me test.</sub>

---

To raise the awareness for problems that might lie in localization, I want to share this experiment with you:

In German we use `,` to separate the decimal digits, where as we use the `.` to group long numbers in thousands.

So if the numberString array might be filled with german formatted numbers, it might look like `@[@"32,5", @"45", @"54", @"5.550,00"]`. The sum of this is `5681.5`, but if we do not alter the code, it will not fail, but worse — miscalculate: `136.55`. It just ignored everything past a comma and treated `.` as decimal separator.

Lets use a NSNumberFormatter to fix it:

My system is set to german locale

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[nf setGroupingSize:3];
nf.usesGroupingSeparator= YES;

NSArray *numberStrings = @[@"32,5", @"45", @"54", @"5.550,00"];
NSMutableArray *numbers = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (NSString *s in numberStrings) {
    NSNumber *n = [nf numberFromString:s];
    [numbers addObject:n];
}


NSNumber* sum = [numbers valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];

NSLog(@"%@", sum);
```

it prints correctly `5681.5`.

Comment: will `[numberStrings valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.intValue"]` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"1,2", @"3,4" ];
NSUInteger sum = 0;
for (NSString *str in array)
{
    for (NSString *num in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","])
    {
        sum += [num intValue];
    }
}
```

or

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"1", @"3" ];
NSUInteger sum = 0;
for (NSString *num in array)
{
    sum += [num intValue];
}
```

Comment: @Zaph it is not clear to me that is the string just number or something like `@"1,2,3"`, but it works either way

Comment: Yes, assume the simplest thing. "Occam's Razor"